# Button tag isn't being recognized as being clicked, with on('click') function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Ok so this is a little weird explanation but I till try to get through it. First off, i am unable to share a lot of code but i will make code that is similar to what is written. Ok so my problem is that I am using an iframe to make a tour on a web page, in said iframe the user should be able to click a button. Once clicked on the left side of the page should be a table of all the elements that can be clicked, in this table it would scroll to the element that is connected to said button in the iframe. Now my problem comes into play here, there are three buttons that aren't doing what i described. Two of them are cancel buttons and the other is a reset to default button(the code for them will be shown). The especially weird thing is that there are other cancel buttons and reset buttons that do work. There is code inside a js file that is a click function, where contentDocument is the body of the iframe, but the ones that dont work never enter this call.

```
$(this.contentDocument).on('click', function(e){ does stuff and things});
```

These are code from the ones that don't work!!!

```
<button type="button" name="btn-basic-form-cancel" id="btn-basic-form-cancel" class="button-small icon-cancel" onclick="">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" name="btn-basic-form-reset" id="btn-basic-form-reset" class="button-small icon-reset" onclick="">Reset to Default</button>
<button type="button" name="btn-advanced-form-cancel" id="btn-advanced-form-cancel" class="button-small icon-cancel" onclick="">Cancel</button>
```

These are code from ones that are working!!!

```
<button type="button" name="btn-advanced-form-reset" id="btn-advanced-form-reset" class="button-small icon-reset" onclick="">Reset</button>
<button type="button" name="btn-ziplookup-form-cancel" id="btn-ziplookup-form-cancel" class="button-small icon-cancel" onclick="">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" name="btn-columns-cancel" id="btn-columns-cancel" class="button-small icon-cancel" onclick="">Cancel</button>
```

Ok so if you any further questions please ask, i tried my best to explain everything but there is a chance that i did miss something. ::UPDATE I have narrowed it down to the fact that those three buttons aren't being recognized to be inside contentDocument, why would they not be if everything else around it is?

Comment: How do the buttons differ i.e. how are they wrapped and created?  Are the ones not working somehow generated dynamically?

Comment: No need for this in the markup: `onclick=""`

Comment: `};` should be `});` on the function  there.

Comment: does `$(this.contentDocument).on('click', 'button', function(e){ console.log(e.target);});` work/log stuff?

Comment: I forgot to put the ) here, my bad, ill edit it. I'll try to add the button part to see if that works. // ok so the adding button didn't work, they are all created the same, none of them are dynamic as well

Comment: I did dynamically change the types to button but in this case they were already button, and i dynamically made onclick='' but since they didnt have an onclick before it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: There appears to be no way to assist you with the  current  information.  Can you post the rendered HTML that includes all these buttons? Can you   post the HTML that includes the `iframe`?  Given the current state, what does this show? `$(this.contentDocument).find('button').length` - should show a count of all the buttons...

Comment: It's hard to share code when im not sure if i am allowed to share it, i will try the find function though

Comment: first off, it is telling me to move it to chat but since i just started here and have no reputation, i can't. Secondly, i did the find function and it does find the buttons that are having problems.

Comment: Here is another idea, try this: `$("iframe").contents().find("button").length`

Comment: It shows up in there as well, i do have a temp fix where i just $(this.contentDocument).find('#btn-basic-form-cancel') instead of this.contentDocument but i would rather not do this. I also did try replacing jq(this.contentDocument) with $("iframe").contents() and it still didnt work for those  buttons

Comment: Since you are new, please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for future questions

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe an ID, then reference it as such:

```
$('#myiframe').load(function(){
  var iframe = $('#myiframe').contents();
  iframe.find("button").on('click',function(e){
      alert("test");
      alert($(e.target).text());// or some such
  });
});
```

OR

```
$("#myiframeid").load( function() {
    $("#myiframeid").contents().on("click", "button", function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

These SHOULD ensure it is loaded prior to attaching the event handler.

Comment: I tried both versions and when i do, either all the buttons don't work or the iframe starts acting up. I'll stick with my temp fix and try to look fir more options, Thanks a lot though you did help me at least find this temp fix.